# Adding mailchimp dkim to existing dkim records

Tags: dns, mailchimp, dkim

I have dkim working fine for a domain for all its own originated emails.

There is an existing DNS DKIM record of default._domainkey.mydomain.com.  with the key that is used and works.

Somebody wants to also use mailchimp to send a some emails on behalf of the organisation.  mailchimp wants me to add:

DKIM: Create a CNAME record for k1._domainkey.mydomain.com with this value: dkim.mcsv.net

Can I just add this record as well?

If not what should be setup to keep mailchimp happy as well as the servers normal emails.

Adding mailchimp to the existing spf record was straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily add the CNAME for `k1._domainkey.example.com` while also having e.g. `default._domainkey.example.com`. One of the features of DKIM is the use of so called "[selectors](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#page-10)". The selector is the hostname before `._domainkey`.

That way you have loads of different key for different services to sign on behalf of your domain. This is completely intentional. When a mail is signed with DKIM, it will also have the selector in the mail, which is then used for the lookup.